# How to check more column values at a time in sqlserver 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

my table:

```
id address tag
1  test   class1
2  test1  class2
3  test3  class3
```

In UI i am displaying all tag names as checkboxes.
When user selects one or more tag names then need to get required address values. how to get?
if user selects class1,class2 in UI then need to get test,test1 as result.
Please tell me how to write query in sqlserver 2008 for that.

EDIT CODE :

```
taglist = "class1,class2";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetTags", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Tags", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = taglist;

                con.Open();

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
```

while passing the parameters as above not getting any results.if i pass single taglist=class1 getting results.but taglist="class1,class2" not getting any resuls.please tell me how to pass multiple parameters from UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the query in sql server by using the [`IN`](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlin.html) keyword.

```
Select address from mytable where tag IN ('class1','class2')
```

EDIT:

Add the parameters with values to the stored procedure like this. The below code is written in C#.net

```
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter1", "class1");
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter2", "class2");
```

EDIT 2:
Its very simple to put in a single string all the values, accordingly your query also suits that. Write the query in your stored procedure like

```
            Select address from mytable where tag IN (@SingleParameter)
```

and in your coding part write like follow

```
            string SingleParameter = "";
            SingleParameter = "class1,class2,class3";
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SingleParameter",SingleParameter);
```

EDIT 3:
Finally i found the solution for your problem. Write your stored procedure as below

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.TestSP
    /*
    (
    @parameter1 int = 5,
    @parameter2 datatype OUTPUT
    )
    */
    @SingleParameter varchar(30)
AS
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
    declare @tags varchar(500)
    set @tags = @SingleParameter
    create table #t (tag varchar(10))
    set @tags = 'insert #t select ' + replace(@tags, ',', ' union select ')
    exec(@tags)
      Select address from sample1 where (tag in (select tag from #t))
    drop table #t
    RETURN
```

and also send the parameters SingleParameter as below

```
            string SingleParameter = "";
            SingleParameter = "'class1','class2','class3'";
            comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SingleParameter",SingleParameter);
```

Comment: i tried but  getting error as invalid column name class1,class2.

Comment: @user1237131, the class1 and class2 are not columns right, they are values in tag column.

Comment: S  they are column values in tag column.i am trying above syntax but getting error as "Invalid column name 'class1'" like that

Comment: How to pass the parameter of tag from UI to SP.i.e 'class1','class2' is it right?

Comment: Need to Give the parameters dynamically.in above example simply we are passing @parameter1,@paramter2 as paramters.Please see my code as above i am passing the parameters like that...

Comment: How to pass all parameters['class1,class2' in one string to SP?Please tell me ...........

Comment: i am placing the checkboxes dynamically in UI.whenever selects the user checkboxes need to check that if the data is avalible or not for the selected checkboxes ,need to get if data available.Dynamically changing passing parameters from UI to SP.so how to pass in a single string of all the selected checkboxes text to SP.....i.e Tag="class1,class2,class3" like that.i tried as i wrote not getting results. if i given Tag="class1" getting results.how to pass multiple parameters in single string?

Comment: i tried the above edited code by you not getting any results if records are there in table.getting dataset as empty.if i given singleparameter="class1" getting results if morethan one not getting i.e singleparameter="class1,class2" then not getting any results dataset returning empty.please tell me what was wrong

Comment: Please help me out yesterday onwards i am trying for that.i am passing the string as you send  not getting any results.

Comment: @user1237131, now refer with the modified code part. You will get the correct result.